# Reset password and Account activation links do not go to the exact URL in my Rails 5 app on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sendgrid, mailer, forgot-password

Now I am developing my maiden website with Ruby on Rails 5.
I have already launched my site on Heroku.
While I am testing it, I found the fact that the account activation link and password reset link are not going to exact link, just go to landing page of my site.
Actually UserMailer is now working well via Sendgrid on Heroku, user receives a confirm email and he or she clicks the link, then not go to password reset page, just redirect to the landing page of my site: namely https://mysite.herokuapp.com.
Why is that?

My production.rb file is the below.

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "mysite.herokuapp.com" }
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true

ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
      :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
      :port           => '587',
      :authentication => :plain,
      :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
      :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
      :domain         => 'mysite.herokuapp.com',
      :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Also password_reset_html.erb for email template is as follows.

```
<h2>Password reset</h2>

<h5>To reset your password click the link below:</h5>

<%= link_to "Reset password", edit_password_reset_url(@user.reset_token, email: @user.email) %></a>
<p>This link will expire in 60 minutes.</p>

<p>
  If you did not request your password to be reset, please ignore this email and
  your password will stay as it is.
</p>
```

And for example, the confirm link in confirmation email is the below.
https://mysite.herokuapp.com/password_resets/X5_WORgqIw4eP7vdKins3g/edit?email=apolloyr%40yahoo.com

Everything is fine, but the last thing - confirmation link redirect to the landing page of my site, not go to the password reset page.

What should I do under this circumstance? Please let me know if you have any idea, and I will appreciate you.

Comment: do you have a `before_action` that is requiring user to be logged in for password reset?

Comment: In my password_resets_controller.rb, before_action is as follows.

Comment: before_action :get_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
before_action :valid_user, only: [:edit, :update]
before_action :check_expiration, only: [:edit, :update]

Comment: Please, in the future, add code to your question. It's too hard to read in comments. So, my quest is: do any of those redirect to landing page if user isn't logged in? Or, any `before_action`s inherited from `ApplicationController` or any other controller?

Comment: If a user is going to log in, but he forgets his password, so he wants to reset password.  He has to input his email address in a form, then a confirmation email is sent to his email address.  Then he clicks the link in his received email, it must go to password reset page, but now it goes to landing page.

Comment: And before_action is not inherited from ApplicationController.

Comment: Perhaps it would be helpful if you added to your question: (a) your routes, and (b) your console log for the request.

Comment: Now I can't test it in my local side because confirmation email can't be sent on localhost.  It occurs a Timeout error.  So I am only testing it on Heroku now.

Comment: you can get the console output from heroku using `heroku logs`. You may need to specify `--remote`, depending on how you have things set up.